# Creating multi-level, scrollable menus using jQuery and the jdMenu plugin

Tags: jquery, menu, usability

In our application we're using [jdMenu plugin](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/) to create a hierarchical menu from nested unordered lists.

[image: example]

This works well until there are so many items in a menu that it is forced off the screen.

[image: it's too big!]

In an attempt to fix this I've updated the plugin (actually the positionBy plugin that is a requirement of jdMenu) so that when a long menu is discovered the plugin reduces the height of the menu (ul), applies overflow:hidden and attempts to place it again. It then attaches a mousemove event to the menu so that when the users moves their mouse up and down the menu scrolls allowing them to see the hidden items. Like so:

[image]

(print screen doesn't capture pointer but on the left screen it's at the top of the menu, on the right it's at the bottom)

This works when it is the last menu in the hierarchy that is too long as above, however if a menu further up the hierarchy is too long then it's sub-menus are not displayed because of the overflow:hidden which has been applied.

So, my question is... is there another way to achieve this effect without using overflow:hidden (or can I use it in a better way)?

Alternatively, is there a more suitable jQuery plugin which will allow me to do something similar?

Let me know if you need any further clarification. Thanks loads.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327928/how-to-load-large-amounts-of-data-in-a-listbox-asp-net-mvc-application/1328049#1328049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone else already answered something like this](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/controls.htm):

> This type of control is seen all too
>   often in corporate applications:
>   drop-down controls and lists that
>   contain thousands of entries.
>
> [image: Some programmers just use a hammer for screws.]
>   <sub>(source: [mac.com](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/images/list2.gif))</sub>
>
> Programmers who mistakenly use it
>   generally get a hint that it might be
>   inappropriate when they find out that
>   it takes an extraordinarily long time
>   to load the form.
>
> The following
>   message, posted in a Visual Basic
>   programmers forum on December 11,
>   1996, is typical:
>
> *I want to fill a
>   list box with 2000 items ... This
>   takes incredibly long ... over 20
>   minutes. Any ideas?*
>
> And another posted
>   on December 16th, 1996, is somewhat
>   less typical:
>
> *I'm looking for a list
>   box control that can ... hold large
>   numbers of entries (20,000+)*
>
> The excuse for such unwieldy controls
>   is often a misguided interpretation of
>   the almighty call to arms, "We must
>   ensure data integrity." The
>   programmers want to make sure that the
>   user specifies a valid entry; in their
>   view, the best way to do this is to
>   force the user to select from a list.
>   That would be fine if you had, say 20,
>   60, or maybe even 100 items in the
>   list. Beyond that number, the fact
>   that the user can only scroll a
>   handful of items at a time causes the
>   control to become unwieldy.

You are actually doing it not so bad, but can I suggest using some other way to do this? More menues? A multi step action?

---

### Edit

You have this structure now:

```
Clients -> 
    Letters of alphabet [A-Z] -> 
        Clients beginning with selected letter -> 
            Contracts belonging to selected client
```

If I **had to use** drop down menus, I'd do the same thing.

But you could make a popup with a "Client" textbox/dropdownbox (only for a small ammount of clients), with autocomplete.

Once you've got the client selected, you'd have a listbox (for small ammounts) of a search feature for searching all the contracts belonging to the client. You could even search by name, date, number, etc.

Once you've selected and checked the contract is the one you are looking for, pressing *OK* would result in the same action you had.

Of course this seems a bit cumbersome next to dropdown menus, but consider that with that ammount of nesting, "search" is faster.

---

One more thing: Don't end up like this! :)

[image: Window madness!]
<sub>(source: [mac.com](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/images/cserve.gif))</sub>

Comment: Yeah, I'm certainly open to alternative approaches. In the example above the menu it used to filter a list of products by contract. As there are hundreds of contracts in the system the menu has been separated out as follows.

Clients -> Letters of alphabet [A-Z] -> Clients beginning with selected letter -> Contracts belonging to selected client.

Where we're having the problem is that we've been asked to miss out the step where we separate clients by first letter. When this happens the list of clients runs off the screen or (if the fix is applied) the user is unable to open the contract menu.

Comment: Great idea. We actually make use of a contract autocomplete elsewhere which searches in the way you mention so this could be implemented fairly easily. This autocomplete also provides a look up button which opens a modal window where the user can page through results, do more detailed searches and of course filter by client by way of a massive long dropdown which goes of the screen. Of course we could replace this with ohmygodithinkiverippedaholeinspaceandtime.

Comment: @jammus: Of course! the HoleInSpaceAndTimeException I see regurarly on corporate apps. It's scary the first thousand times, after that it just gets old :)

Answer (score 1):

As well as using Autocomplete, why not also list the 5 most recent selected Clients. So if your switching between items around the application, you can always find the most recent client you selected.

It would be interesting to do some user testing with different solutions to this problem, use some [screen recording software](http://silverbackapp.com) and see how you could improve the user-experience.

Comment: I really like this and will making use of it elsewhere. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This [jQuery ListMenu](http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/demos/current/jquery-listmenu-plugin.aspx) might be an idea for you.. it's not a multi-level menu system, but it might be cleaner to organize your list using the alphabet.